# Prestashop Class CacheXc not found

Tags: php, caching, prestashop

I was in admin, wen't to disable xcache (caching disabled), then it just started to load for long time and I noticed my connection interrupted (lost connection to network).

Now I'm getting error `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CacheXc' not found in ... /classes/cache/Cache.php on line 131` and can't enter admin or frontend anymore, just getting white page.

Is there a way to disable cache manually, IF it helps ?

Any other solutions ?